# Fisher's combined test vs testing uniform distribution of p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, combining-p-values

In testing a global null hypothesis, with independent tests, the p-values are distributed as $U(0,1)$. There are many goodness-of-fit tests to check that the distribution is uniform. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/430688/6474) discusses the use of chi-squared, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, and several others.

However, in [many articles](https://brainder.org/2012/05/11/the-logic-of-the-fisher-method-to-combine-p-values/) about combining test results, I've seen the recommendation to use [Fisher's combined test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method#Application_to_independent_test_statistics). Does it have any specific advantage for global null testing, compared to the more widely used tests of uniformity that I listed above?

Comment: It's a good question.  When thinking about it, be sure to consider (a) tests based on discrete statistics (such as counts) and (b) tests based on composite hypotheses (such as $H_0:\mu\le 0$ *versus* $H_A:\mu\gt 0$).  I believe both of those situations provide counterexamples to your supposition of uniformly distributed p-values when the null is true.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the combination of $p$-values is that the question is usually not well specified. The methods available fall into two groups which are more sensitive to either (a) at least one $p_i$ is not from the uniform distribution (b) they all are not. Fisher's method is quite sensitive in situation (a) whereas Stouffer's method is sensitive in situation (b).